# which libraries must be imported while using neo4j with ecllipse for database connectivity?

Tags: neo4j

which libraries must be imported while using neo 4j with eclipse for database connectivity?

Should i use eclipse libraries or not?

please help

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [developer site for Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/)? Also, please show us any code you have tried using so far with a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using neo 4j with eclipse for database connectivity"?